# Insert image or link links

Tags: wysiwyg, files

When in edit, and presented with a wysiwyg editor for example, I've got a "Switch to plain text editor" link under. However, in one of the sites, in addition to this link I also have  "Insert image or link" links. But not in the other sites. Where is this setting coming from? Is it generally good practice to have these links?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that there is a limit... @NikhilM

Comment: There is no limit. but there is a possibility of getting blocked. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few standard "Text formats" for a text field. Which one you actually can use depends on your permission settings (for example permission `Use the Full HTML text format`).

Then you have the settings for each of the text format (admin/config/content/formats), there you can set up what options a specific format has (you can add/remove image/link buttons).

The last thing to know is that order in which text formats are listed in the administrator page is important. It decides which text format is used as a default. A typical problem with ordering of text formats are automatic messages with broken links (result of "Plain text" format having too high priority).

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the IMCE configuration page (/admin/settings/imce) you'll find a section labeled: "Enable inline image/file insertion into plain textareas:"

You should be able to edit the value in this configuration field (or remove it altogether) to remove these links from your add/edit pages.